# No Route Matches Action (When method exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, edit

I think that I must be calling the edit action with incorrect parameters. I am, however, unsure.

In an arbitrary index view, I have the line

```
<%= link_to "Update", 
                edit_employee_document_path(:company_document_id => document.id, :file => document.file) %>
```

When I click the link, it gives me an error which says

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"employee_documents", :company_document_id=>3, :file=>/system/company_documents/files/000/000/003/original/avatarAvatar.html?1375383810}
```

My controller should be working. Here is the edit method:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:employee_id])
    @employee_document = EmployeeDocument.find(params[:id])
  end
```

To anyone that can help, I thank you greatly!

Comment: have you specified 'resources :employee_documents' in routes.rb?

Comment: Yeah. Looks like --- resources :employee_documents, :path => "/documents", :as => :documents

Comment: then do 'rake routes | grep documents' and show me the result.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for this one:   edit_employee_document GET    /employees/:employee_id/documents/:id/edit(.:format) employee_documents#edit

Comment: you want to call update method on click of this link. Right?

Comment: Nah, I want to call the edit method to render the edit form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see that you have passed the employee_id, and document id, into key 'id' and 'employee_id'

try this out

```
<%= link_to "Update", 
                edit_employee_document_path(:id => document.id, :employee_id => some_employee.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call edit method on this link click than, you should try this:-

```
 <%= link_to "Update", 
            edit_employee_document_path(document.id) %>
```

Hope this will help. Thanks